# How to undo the partition that was done using gdisk el captain iMac 9,1

Tags: hard-drive, macos, bootcamp, imac, partition

Long story short:
This year I decided i want to try and get Windows 10 on my iMac 2009 for some gaming as it had Windows 7. I succeed upgraded to Windows 10 but it was 32 bit, not 64 that I require, so I tried to reinstall using bootcamps and have new partition, and there was a single corrupt byte that wouldn't let me partition. 
It required completed new reinstall of El Captain which was pain, but worked in the end. Bootcamp still wouldn't let me install Windows 10, so I had to install it manually. I have dome a couple of configuration along the way, as it require some disk configuration and GPT.
Window 10 didn't work as well as I hoped for, it was too laggy. So I decided this iMac no longer useful apart from internet browsing or sorting photo album. So I would like to return it to one partition using El Captain only. That require undoing the configurations I have done to the disk.

This is my gdisk output:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5
Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
```

and my disk currently:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *640.1 GB   disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Tararua                 439.9 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS EFI                     199.2 GB   disk0s4
   5:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s5
```

disk0s2 is the El Captain OS Xdrive. I would like to see disk0s4, disk0s5, and disk0s1 removed and its space added to disk0s2. Disk0s4 was my attempt to have it merged with Tararua using terminal but somehow it failed, it just renamed itself and changed to OS extended from exFAT.

Given how it was painful to install El Captain, I would like to avoid having to reinstall that.

[image: Disk Utility image of the drive][image: Partition image]

Any instructions to return to one partition using terminal please, thanks

Comment: Your partition table looks kinda weird. disk0s1 is supposed to be your ESP (EFI System Partition), but it's not named EFI for some reason. Keep in mind that you NEED an ESP, preferably on disk0s1, so no, don't delete that. Could you check if it contains an EFI folder, which in turn contains APPLE and potentially Microsoft and Boot? You can mount it with sudo diskutil mount disk0s1. Also check what's in disk0s4, as it appears to be an ESP too (one intended for booting Macs only, since it's in HFS+) but is way too big for an ESP. See what it contains, we want to know for sure before deleting it.

Comment: disk0s4 is nothing, it used to be Microsoft Windows 10 but has been erased, somehow was renamed to EFI when it is not supposed to.
disk0s1 gets the error "failed to mount" 
I agree it is weird cos the disk0s1 wasn't even appearing in Disk Utilty before I partitioned for Windows, and now it is

Comment: You tried with sudo? You need an ESP, otherwise you won't get security and firmware updates and in general your setup will be non-standard.

Comment: Yes:
```
Antons-iMac:~ Bracia$ sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
Password:
Volume on disk0s1 failed to mount
If the volume is damaged, try the "readOnly" option
```

[![Info from disk utility of the disk0s1][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbYbE.png

Comment: if it is any help, I can rename disk0s4 to Akatarawa, but I can't rename disk0s1

Comment: Did you try to do what it says, try the readOnly option?

Comment: Hi Machineel, Yeah it says the same error:

Volume on disk0s1 failed to mount. If the volume is damaged, try the readOnly option. 

The code i used is

sudo distil mount readOnly  /dev/disk0s1

Comment: If it is any help, `diskutil` output shows the type for `disk0s1` is wrong. Instead of `Apple_HFS`, you should see `EFI`.

Comment: Thanks David, is there a way to change disk0s1 to EFI?